# updated dll not being called in c# project

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a C# Project,which consist of multiple projects ,which are built already and I am calling it through list of dll(say it is main list of dll eg..(a.dll,p.dll,v.dll)).

One of the dll say a.dll is calling few functions existing on b.dll.(function call).The b.dll does not exist in the main list of dll...it is only called by a.dll and sometime by an other exe that is say g.exe.The exe is executed directly by passing the name of exe in other dll from main list and again exe in calling the function existed in b.dll.
I have changed one file in b.dll and rebuild all dll separately and then build whole solution and .....but the changes are not reflected in output file.

a.dll----->b.dll

p.dll--->g.exe--->b.dll

here a.dll and p.dll are in the main list.

Please suggest some option which I can try out to update the output.

Comment: What are you mean by "calling it through list of dll"?

Comment: Make sure you copy all of the dlls to the folder where your .exe is launched from.

Comment: Are you sure you have a project reference? Is you're configuration manager setup correctly to build the dependency assemblies. Have you cleaned the solution? Check the properties of the reference and make sure the path is as you expect

Comment: there is a list of dlls in an xml file....there is a program which is taking and executing these dll sequentially....it is showing me the output...but not the updated one...paths are also managed through xml

Comment: Alex: I have checked the dll locations ..they exist on my bin/debug and obj/debug and the location from where the program's main is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Check references of all projects may be some may refer to dll on other location.
Delete reference and add it from Projects tab when you select reference if all projects in one solution.

Comment: Hi...I tried to remove the project dependency but it says "This dependency was added by the project system and can not be removed".....then I tried to follow accepted solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818315/error-while-removing-project-dependency-in-vs2010...there is .csproj file...in that i checked ....there is no <ProjectReference> tag...I also deleted the older dll and rebuild everything ....but that also didn't work....

Comment: I have deleted the reference and added it from project tab....but still not updated...:(